# Sass selector with ampersands, plus with OR on another class

Tags: css, sass

I have a list of buttons that look like this:

```
<button class="PatientImage-button"> <img src="1"> </button>
<button class="PatientImage-button"> <img src="2"> </button>
<button class="PatientImage-button"> <img src="3"> </button>
<button class="PatientImage-button active"> <img src="4"> </button>
<button class="PatientImage-button"> <img src="5"> </button>
```

And the highlighting is done through a css style `border-color: #000000`.

Clicking the button calls an event which updates the button's class to include `active`. Also hovering and focusing on the button should do that too.

I'm trying to get the sass selectors correct so that I don't have to write `border-color: #000000` twice in the file. Here's what works:

```
.PatientImage {
  &-button {
    padding: 2px;
    &:hover, &:focus {
      border-color: #000000; 
    }
  }
}
.active {
  border-color: #000000; 
}
```

Is there a way with Sass selectors I can do something like this? (doesn't work)

```
.PatientImage {
  &-button {
    padding: 2px;
    &:hover, &:focus, .active {
      border-color: #000000; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try putting `&` before `.active`? Without `&` it's looking for a child element with class `active` inside `.PatientImage-button`. E.g.: `&:hover, &:focus, &.active {`?

Comment: That works, thank you...your answer got poached 4 minutes later

Comment: Yeah :( Oh well. You live you learn I guess ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
.PatientImage-button{
  padding: 2px;
  &:hover, &:focus,&.active{
    border-color: #000000; 
  }
}
```